# Is there way to keep an application running on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, ssh, shared-hosting, ngrok, localtunnel

I am using Ngrok (https://ngrok.com/) application on my Godaddy Linux server to create a  local-tunnel to my host.

However, I access the server through SSH and run the application but when I exit from the SSH connection the application stops running, so **is there way to keep Ngrok application running (as a service maybe) on a Linux server?**

**NOTE:** I don't have root access on Godaddy server, so the whatever the solution should be able to proceed as a non root user

Comment: Run the application using `nohup`.

Comment: look here for answer http://serverfault.com/questions/311593/keeping-a-linux-process-running-after-i-logout.Also look http://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

Comment: @Barmar thanks nohup worked well

Comment: @Jayesh thanks, `screen` is also seem to work but `tmux` is not installed on Godaddy shared-hosting server

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GNU screen.
`screen`

When you install screen and open it run your commands inside then exit it. There are a lot of infos about that in google so check it there

and then you are able to exit with CTRL + A then CTRL + D

hope it helped you

Comment: `screen` is one of many tools to solve this. A more detailed answer how to use `screen` would be helpful

Comment: When you install screen and open it run your commands inside then exit it. There are a lot of infos about that in google